# how to prevent j,query ajax multiple request on date change event

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to prevent  multiple request when i am change the date from date picker this is my code but it not work properly its send two ajax request when change a date.

```
$('.datepicker#vm_avail_date').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    //startDate: '+1d',
    //startDate: new Date()
}).on("changeDate", function (e){
    actions.courtlist_courtdata(); //function 
});
```

but when i am changing a date

`actions.courtlist_courtdata()` call two time in server its properlly work on server why??

Answer (score 0):

Use timeout with flag to control calling function multiple time.

```
    var temp=true;
    if(temp){
    temp=false;
    setTimeout(function(){
    actions.courtlist_courtdata(); 
    temp=true;
    },200)
   }
```